# Promise rejected "reject is not defined" in my chain of Promises

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have the following chain of Promises:

```
let promise         = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    imgToDisplay.onload = () => {
        resolve(imgToDisplay.width);
    }
})
.then((result) => {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(imgToDisplay.src);
    if (result >= 20)
        reject('Image width too large');
})
.then(() => {   
    //I do something with the image file here if it is not rejected
})
.catch((e) => {
    alert(e.message); //This happened, however "reject is not defined"
});
```

I did not `reject` nor `resolve` my Promise in the second `then()`. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: correct, it is not defined in that callback ... use `throw '...'` or return `Promise.reject('...')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're *directly inside* the Promise constructor, you can't call `reject`, because it's not in scope. But, if you throw an error inside the `.then`, you can force the control flow to go to the next `.catch` in the chain (skipping `.then`s in between):

```
let promise         = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  imgToDisplay.onload = () => {
    resolve(imgToDisplay.width);
  }
})
.then((result) => {
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(imgToDisplay.src);
  if (result >= 20)
    // This will result in the Promise being rejected:
    throw new Error('Image width too large');
})
.then(() => {   
  //I do something with the image file here if it is not rejected
})
.catch((e) => {
  alert(e.message); //This happened, however "reject is not defined"
});
```

In this case though, since the test that results in the rejected Promise can be done *in the Promise constructor*, you could call `reject` in the constructor instead, if you wanted:

```
let promise         = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  imgToDisplay.onload = () => {
    if (imgToDisplay.width >= 20) {
      reject('Image width too large');
    }
    resolve(imgToDisplay.width);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `throw` instead of reject in `then` callback

```
let promise         = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    imgToDisplay.onload = () => {
        resolve(imgToDisplay.width);
    }
})
.then((result) => {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(imgToDisplay.src);
    if (result >= 20)
        throw 'Image width too large';
})
.then(() => {   
    //I do something with the image file here if it is not rejected
})
.catch((e) => {
    alert(e.message); //This happened, however "reject is not defined"
});
```